# Access Qt resource files in VS 2017 with CMake

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake

I am having trouble accessing qt resource files in a VS 2017 project with CMake. I was able to access the qrc files using Qt Creator. I have the following questions:

- Where do I put the resource files? Preferably I would like to put resource files in the root directory. I have tried to put the files in the root director and in the directory they will be called.
- What changes I should make to the CMakeLists.txt files?
- How can I refer to the resource files? I have tried all the instruction I can find on internet. But none of them seem to work. For example I have tried: ":/prefix/filepath/filename" or ":prefix/filepath/filename".

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `.qrc` file where you want, for my project I make it on `/res` folder but is your choice. You can add your files on the resources edit manually the `.qrc` file as a normal xml file. Here a simple example:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/menu_img">
        <file alias="cancel_img">icons/cancel-512.png</file>
        <file alias="open_img">icons/folder-512.png</file>
        <file alias="print_img">icons/printer-512.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

In this resource files the images are inside the folder `icons` and the `.qrc` is outside.

After that your `.qrc` file is ready (assuming that you use qt5) you must add to your `CMakeList.txt` this line:

`qt5_add_resources(PROJECT_RESOURCE path_to_rosource_file/resources.qrc)`

then on your target you must add this rosource:

```
add_executable(
   ${TARGET_PROJECT}
   ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
   ${PROJECT_HEADERS}
   ${PROJECT_RESOURCES})
```

Now your resources is available inside your project as usual `:/menu_img/cancel_img`

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. After I added the resources.qrc to PROJECT_RESOURCE, CMake automatically changes the file name from resource.qrc to qrc_resources.cpp. It then says it cannot find the file. Can you please help me understand why?

Comment: Is perfectly normal that the file `qrc_resources.cpp` was created (this is the manner witch Qt add the resources to your binary target) what is strange is that this file is created in the same folder whit your other files. That suggest me that you don't use CMake correctly. All CMake temporary files should be created on another directory `build` for example for avoid getting dirty your project root.

Comment: My apology for the confusion. I was trying to say CMake expects the .cpp files in the build folder but can't find it. I searched the build folder and found some files for with extension ".depends ". However I did not find .cpp files for qrc. I already set CMAKE_AUTORCC to on.